# I'm Making a set of frameworks. I want to support multiple programming languages

Tags: frameworks, programming-languages, libraries

I'm Making a set of frameworks.

I want to support multiple programming languages.

My question is what language should i use as the base?

and is there a way to multiple bindings?

I want to support all these programming languages.

```
C, C++, Java, Ruby, Perl, Python.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement the library in C++. If you need C access, then this is easily done by hand, by providing wrapper functions that take an additional "this" argument.

Before you start though, read the [SWIG](http://swig.org) documentation, in particular its limitations and things to avoid. If you design your C++ interface with SWIG in mind you can get the bindings for a lot of languages generated for you without effort.

**Edit**: Here is a quick example of a C wrapper for a C++ class. Let's say this is the C++ class to wrap, let's call it `test.h`:

```
class Test {
public:
    Test();
    int do_something(char* arg);
private:
    is_valid(); // see below for why you need this method
};
```

This is your C header `test_c.h`:

```
typedef void* TestHandle;
TestHandle newTest();
int deleteTest(TestHandle h);
int Test_do_something(TestHandle h, char* arg);
```

And your C implementation will be a C++ file with C functions, let's say `test_c.cpp`:

```
extern "C" TestHandle newTest()
{
    return (void*)new Test();
}

extern "C" int deleteTest(TestHandle h)
{
    Test* this = static_cast<Test*>(h);
    if (!this->is_valid())
        return -1; // here we define -1 as "invalid handle" error
    delete this;
    return 0; // here we define 0 as the "ok" error code
}

extern "C" int Test_do_something(TestHandle h, char* arg)
{
    Test* this = static_cast<Test*>(h);
    if (!this->is_valid())
        return -1; // here we define -1 as "invalid handle" error
    return this->do_something(arg);
}
```

The `is_valid()` method is there to guarantee that you are not passed a bad handle. For example, you can store a [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) in all your instances, then `is_valid()` just ensures the magic number is there.

Comment: I like the idea but could you show an example of C++ C wrapper like you are talking about?

Comment: I have updated my answer with an C wrapper example.

Comment: Thank you this will work perfectly I'm new here when I get points i will vote you up but i can't till people quit voting me down ps: on a final question do you think it is possible to have the C wrapper in the same binary with the C++ classes,functions?

Comment: Sure, C and C++ can coexist in the same binary.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [GObject](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/) — it's an open-source C library that adds object-oriented programming functionality for C, and can transparently create bindings for [a variety of languages](http://live.gnome.org/GObjectIntrospection/Users).

And its companion, [Vala](http://live.gnome.org/Vala), is an object-oriented language that compiles down to C+GObject code, to help cut down on the verbosity of C+GObject.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [SWIG](http://swig.org/), "Simplified Wrapper and Interface Generator".  Given C or C++ code, it can programmatically generate bindings for [a variety of languages](http://swig.org/compat.html#SupportedLanguages).